# How to Make HTML Login Page Only on Client Side?

Tags: javascript, html

Just for learning purposes, I want to make an insecure HTML5 "login page" which handles everything on the client side.

```
<div class="login">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login">
            </div>

<script>
        function check(form) { 
            if(login.username.value == "guest" && login.password.value == "pwrd") {
                window.open('home.html')
            }
            else {
                alert("Error Password or Username")
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I think it  is not a good idea to get the password on the client side.

Comment: See this example: http://m.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL of how to truly create a login system.

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer an the answer. Check the check box next to my answer.

Comment: You need to perform the validation server-side (for example using PHP). However you can display error messages with Javascript using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation should be done on the client side only, validation like required, alphanumeric, only numbers etc. Checking the username and password should be done on the server side, using ajax and simple PHP query to check username and password from the table.

If you are looking for front end html only then html5 provides nice validation already like for required and email and numbers only.

eg: `<input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required>`

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
```

Here is a nice tutorial for creating a login form.
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-loginpage/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use JavaScript to make a login page...The user can modify your script and bypass the login script.

Also, there is no such thing as a simple login system. You have to use databases and verify EVERY page to make sure the user is allowed and is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use php :

1.html Form :

```
    <form action="your_page.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Connect" />
    </form>
```

2.php Work now :

```
      <?php 

       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    //when user click connect
          if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){ 
               if ($_POST['username']=="guest" && $_POST['password']=="pwrd"){

               header("Location:home.php");
              }else{
           echo"check the password and username";
      }
        }else{
          echo"fill all the inputs";
         }
       }
```

Comment: but u have to know that this is not secured at all. you need to use $_SEESION variables if you are interested tell me i can help you . and it's more easy than javascript don't you be scared